# SQL Server Managment Studio 2012 With Other Versions Of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I know it might sound naïve but is there's anyway to use the SSMS 2012 with SQL Server 2008 as it's our deployment server but I really hate the absence of Intellisense SSMS 2008 and it makes me waste a lot of time that makes using the GUI much more reasonable option

Comment: You are lookng for intellisense feature in SSMS 2012?

Comment: Have you *tried*? How long does it take to attempt this versus asking a question on SO and waiting for answers?

Comment: try to use alternative tool like dbForge - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SSMS 2012 from the installation media of SQL Server 2012. Or as an alternative you can download and use SSMS 2016, which is still in beta, but can be downloaded and updated separately from a database engine - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx. It has all features of SSMS 2012 and more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've used SSMS 2012 and 2014 against our production 2008 and 2008R2 SQL server instances.

Answer (score 0):

I have used SSMS2012 against multiple versions of SQL Server (2008R2, 2012 and even 2014) and I have not encountered any problems so far. Anyway, I expect to be fully backward compatible, so it should work fine with 2008R2.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't so clear in my question that I want to know how to actually do it not just knowing the ability for it to happen